# Navigating from one fragment via another via onClick, android

Tags: java, android, fragment

How do you navigate from one fragment to another, where one fragment extends the other? I want to navigate from the child fragment to the parent fragment via a button. Since the child fragment inherits from the parent fragment, they use the same onCreate method, and therefore also inflating the same view. I have tried to use replace, but I'm not able to find the id of the fragment that should be replaced.

```
 Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(id,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello create a method like this

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String newid, String oldId, int resId) {
    
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(resId, fragment, newid)
            .addToBackStack(oldId)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don’t know what Id to use as resId. Both fragments uses the same xml, so they don’t have their own Id from the layout.

Comment: In resId just pass fragment tag Id